# SQL string to varbinary through XML different than nvarchar

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, varbinary

We currently have a function in SQL which I simply do not understand.

Currently we convert a nvarchar to XML, and then select the XML value, and convert that to a varbinary.

When I try to simplify this to convert the nvarchar directly to varbinary, the output is different... Why?

```
--- Current situation:
Declare @inputString nvarchar(max) = '4d95605d1b8f3bca5ea3e0d2af26027004d17218152e726da0622d669a71f85c'

--1: input to XML
declare @inputXML XML = convert(varchar(max), @inputString)

--2: input XML to binary
declare @inputBinray varbinary(max) = @inputXML.value('(/)[1]', 'varbinary(max)')

select @inputString -- 4d95605d1b8f3bca5ea3e0d2af26027004d17218152e726da0622d669a71f85c
select @inputXML -- 4d95605d1b8f3bca5ea3e0d2af26027004d17218152e726da0622d669a71f85c
select @inputBinray -- 0xE1DF79EB4E5DD5BF1FDDB71AE5E6B77B477669FDBAD36EF4D38775EF6D7CD79D9EEF6E9D6B4EB6D9DEBAF5AEF57FCE5C
```

```
--- New situation
--1: Input to binary
declare @inputString2 varbinary(max) = CAST(@inputString as varbinary(max));

select @inputString2 -- 0x3400640039003500360030003500640031006200380066003300620063006100350065006100330065003000640032006100660032003600300032003700300030003400640031003700320031003800310035003200650037003200360064006100300036003200320064003600360039006100370031006600380035006300
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `value()` function to get a XML value specified as `varbinary(max)` will read the data as if it was Base64 encoded. Casting a string to varbinary(max) does not, it treats it as just any string.

If you use the input string `QQA=` which is the letter `A` in UTF-16 LE encoded to Base64 you will see more clearly what is happening.

XML gives you `0x4100`, the varbinary of the letter `A`, and direct cast on the string gives you `0x5100510041003D00` where you have two `5100 = "Q"` and of course one `4100 = "A"` followed by a `3D00 = "="`

Answer (score 1):

Might be I get something wrong, but - if I understand you correctly - I think you simply want to get a **real binary** from a HEX-string, which just *looks* like a binary. Correct?

Above I wrote *"simply"*, but this was not simple at all a while ago.

I'm not sure at the moment, but I think it was version v2012, which enhanced `CONVERT()` (read about binary values and how the third parameter works) and try this:

```
DECLARE @hexString VARCHAR(max)='4d95605d1b8f3bca5ea3e0d2af26027004d17218152e726da0622d669a71f85c';

SELECT CONVERT(varbinary(max),@hexString,2);
```

The result is a **real** binary

```
0x4D95605D1B8F3BCA5EA3E0D2AF26027004D17218152E726DA0622D669A71F85C
```

What might be the reason for your issue:

Very long ago, I think it was until v2005, the default encoding of varbinaries in XML was a HEX string. Later this was changed to base64. Might be, that you code was used in a very old environment and was upgraded to a higher version?

Today we use XML in a smiliar way to create and to read base64, which is not supported otherwise. Maybe your code did something similar with HEX strings...?

One more hint for this: The many `00` in your *New Situation* example show clearly, that this is a two-byte encoded `NVARCHAR` string. Contrary, your *Current Situation* shows a simple HEX string.

Your *final result* is just the binary pattern of your input as string: